# How can I determine whether a Grapheme Cluster is alphabetic?

Tags: unicode

I've been reading through the [unicode text segmentation documentation](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) and it appears that I can probably apply the alphabetic property of the base character in the cluster (ie the first unicode scalar) to the cluster as a whole but I'm struggling to find a definitive answer.